# If five teams are playing in a round robin tournament, is it possible for all five teams to tie for the first place?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

If five teams are playing in a round robin tournament, is it possible for all five teams to tie for the first place? What if six teams are playing?

Comment: How many games does each team play? What would their record have to be for everyone to tie? Are these conditions consistent with rghthndsd's hint?

Comment: In futbol soccer, yes, definitely.

Comment: As Pocho la pantera’s comment implies, it depends on whether individual matches can result in a tie. You are almost certainly intended to assume, as rghthndsd and Kevin Driscoll have done, that they cannot.

Comment: Good point, Brian. I never considered individual matches resulting in ties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, consider an $n$-player single round robin tournament with no tie games (it might be a [hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29) [*] tournament). Clearly, an $n$-way tie means that every player breaks even, winning exactly half of his, her, their, or its games. And that's clearly impossible if $n$ is even, as each player has an odd number of games.

Now suppose $n$ is odd. Regard the players as vertices and the games as edges of the complete graph $K_n$. Since the graph is connected and every vertex has even degree, there is an [Eulerian circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in the graph. (That's a closed walk which traverses each edge exactly once.) Choose an Eulerian circuit and give it a direction. Plainly, as we follow the Eulerian circuit, we enter any given vertex the same number of times as we leave it. In other words, an Eulerian circuit defines an orientation of the graph in which the outdegree of each vertex is equal to its indegree, i.e., every player breaks even, $n$-way tie.

[*] Because ties are impossible in hex. However, a hex tournament should preferably be a *double* round robin, because of the big first-player advantage.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: How many games total are played in each situation?

Answer (score 2):

In total there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ total matchups (each player plays each other player but we divide by $2$ since this double counts).  So for $n=5$ we get $10$ matchups and $10$ is divisible by $5$ so it's certainly possible.  This graph illustrates that the case for $5$ players *is* possible.  Each edge represents a matchup and an arrow pointing at a player indicates they have won.

[image]

**EDIT:** Please note the graph is missing an arrow point from $2$ to $4$. Thanks Brian.

The case for $6$ players is not possible since there are $\frac{6(6-1)}{2} = 15$ total matchups which is not divisible by $6$.

Comment: The divisibility of $10$ by $5$ is a **necessary** condition for the existence of a $5$-way tie, but it’s not self-evidently sufficient, so *certainly possible* is an overstatement. The graph, on the other hand, does show that it’s possible. (The edge from $2$ to $4$ is missing its arrow.)

Comment: Ok. I just realized *certainly possible* is an oxymoron too. I don't think I'll use that anymore.

Comment: No, it’s not an oxymoron: it just says that one is certain that something actually could occur, though it might be very, very improbable. It is certainly possible, for example, that random motion of the molecules will take all of the air in this room to within a foot of the ceiling as I type this sentence, though I’m not wasting on worry on that possibility.